# Area attack collision resolving

Tags: collision-detection

I'm planning to write little 2D go-right-and-swing-your-sword game. When i started to write my ideas on paper i've come across a little problem.
Let's say i'm using magic spell, ex. fireball which technically is a signle projectile flying slowly in a specified direction. As it's defined to be a piercing projectile, I want it to hit every enemy only once, no matter how big their sprites are. And how I do it?
I know i can use the array of already hit enemies and check every frame if projectile collides something new, but is it a correct way? Are there any tried and true ways of resolving problems like this?

Comment: If the hit is only considered when the projectile is entering the enemy's BBox / collision geometry, wouldn't it be ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways to do this:

1. An array on the enemy that keeps track of what fire ball has hit it and check against it every time there is a collision.
2. As you have already suggested: an array of identifiers of enemies that have been hit by the fireball.

Now you have to ask *"Who's responsible for calculating the damage of the fireball on the enemies?"*, if you answer "The fireball", then the approach you suggested, 2., is the way to go: unless the enemy knows anything about a fireball, there is no need for it to keep track of those; the fireball however should probably know about the enemies.

Another option is that if your fireball and your enemies are completely decoupled and the damage is managed by a 3rd party (e.g. 'DamageManager'), well in this case, the DamageManager will have to keep track of the enemies and fireballs combinations that have occurred and not re-apply the damage.

To be honest, however, ultimately, as long as it fits your game architecture, and it's efficient enough (you check that by using a profiler), any method to make it work is ok :)

Answer (score 0):

A completely different aproach may be: 
consider your "fireball" (or area weapon) damage as **HP per second**. And every step you calculate the damage in this way

```
 enemy.HP = enemy.HP - firebal.damagePerSec * dt
```

where dt is your frame delta time.

I know this is a bit out of target , as your question is very specific.